# scope of element names in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to name and then set a DataContext for a ComboBox that's embedded within an ItemsControl.

In my main Window, I can access the ItemsControl by name but not any of the elements within the ItemsControl.

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SList.DataContext = App.SCList; //this is valid
        StS.DataContext = App.STList; //this is not
    }
```

And here's the XAML code. I can access SList from within the program but not "StS" or "SPanel1". The compiler error is:
"The name 'StS' does not exist in the current context"

Note that I've tried both "Name" and "x:Name"

```
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  >
            <ItemsControl Name ="SList" ItemsSource ="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Margin="12"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5" Margin="8,8" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Beige">
                            <StackPanel Name="SPanel1">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Content="S Type"/>
                                <ComboBox Name ="StS" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ShipType.TypeName, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="STList">
                                </ComboBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Content="Class Name"/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path = Name, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Accessining StS from code-behind is not possible, because it is declared inside the data template. Is `STList` a static member of class `App`? If yes, then try `<ComboBox ... DataContext="{x:Static App.STList}">`

Comment: @fmunkert Thanks, it was a static list so "DataContext="{x:Static local:App.STList}" gives me access.